# Win 7 can't find local network after WmWare Workstation 7 installation

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation

This is the sequence of installation.

1. I just installed Windows 7 x64 and it works great!
2. I installed rollback to manage system-states and it works great!
3. I shared the resources with my WinXP machine over my local network, mapped up a network-drive for my NAS, saved a system-state and it works great!
4. I installed WmWare workstation 7, saved a system-state and now i can't find any network resources.
5. Rolled back to state 3 and I can find XP and my NAS, it works works great!
6. Rolled back to state 4 with Workstation 7 and I need advice, help, a pray, a spell and more sugar. I have searched the web, checked local group policies, firewall settings, disabled wmware network adaptors and im stuck. Nothing out of the ordinary.

Any idea why windows 7 stop showing local network resources after i install workstation 7?

Answer (score 1):

VMware Workstation installs some virtual network adapters to deal with the various types of virtual networking you can configure on your VMs.  Those virtual network adapters are configured for somewhat random 192.168.x.x subnets at install time.  It's possible your real local network is conflicting with one of the ones setup by VMware, though I would've thought the installer was smart enough to not do that.

Run **ipconfig** in a cmd prompt and see if any of the VMware Network Adapters share the same subnet as your real network adapter.  All of them most likely have an IPv4 address that starts with 192.168.  The third number in that address is the subnet.

If you have a conflict, you can use the VMware Virtual Network Editor to change the VMware subnets to something different.

Answer (score -1):

Use [Parallels Desktop for Windows](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/pd4wl/) it works fine on my Windows 7 host +)